# Puppet: manage the recursiveness of owner/group/mode attributes separately

Tags: puppet

I need to write a Puppet script to manage the directory `/foo/bar` such that:

1. the file mode on `/foo/bar` is `777`, but the permissions of everything within the directory are not managed by Puppet.
2. the owner/group on `/foo/bar` and everything within it is `baz`.

That is, the first requirement is non-recursive, but the second attribute is recursive.

Puppet provides a single `recursive` attribute, which affects the behavior of `owner`, `group`, and `mode` simultaneously. This means that I cannot specify the desired behavior using a single resource declaration.

I tried using two resource declarations, but then I get the error

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: File[/foo/bar] is already declared in file /my/puppet/file.pp at line XX; cannot redeclare
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is completely trivially easy in CFEngine, which is *actually* a tool to model your desired state, unlike Puppet.  In CFEngine you can literally just say, `files: "/foo/bar/." perms => m(777); "foo/bar/." perms => og("baz", "baz"), depth_search => recurse("inf");` — done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will not work. Mind that Puppet is not a scripting engine, but a tool to model your desired state.

You will therefor have to decide how you want to manage your directory: As a single file system entry (`recurse => false`) or a whole tree (`recurse => true`). In the latter case, Puppet will always manage all properties for which you are passing values.

In your situation, you will likely have to fall back to the workaround of managing the permissions of the directory itself through a different resource, likely an `exec` resource that calls `chmod`, independently of the `file` resource. The latter *must not* pass a value for `mode` in this constellation, otherwise the two resources will always work against one another.

It's no ideal, but Puppet is not well equipped to deal with your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks. That's a shame.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but I disagree with the statement that "Puppet is not a scripting engine, but a tool to model your desired state."  The use case in the question is a very simple one, with two requirements stated very simply. If Puppet lived up to being a tool to model your desired state, those two requirements would translate exactly to two small snippets of code, the way they do in CFEngine, which IS a tool to model desired state. The fact that in Puppet you have to work around this *by scripting* just shows it is unable to model your desired state here, which is a language failure.